# No puedo actualizar puntos de Polyline C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Para explicar un poco de donde viene el problema, en la versión anterior de mi programa tenía 2 objetos polyline declarados en el MainWindows.XAML (Un triangulo y un cuadrado) y los mostraba y ocultaba según necesitara, estos objetos tenían un evento que reproducía un audio cuando el puntero del mouse entraba a la figura (MouseEnter) y lo detenía cuando el puntero salía de la figura (MouseLeave).

En mi nuevo programa necesito mas flexibilidad y poder editar las figuras por lo que declaro las polilyne directamente desde el código.

```
public Polyline dibujoOriginal = new Polyline();
```

entonces con colección de puntos puedo editar los puntos. El problema viene a la hora de querer mostrar esa figura.
Declaré un objeto polyline auxiliar en el XAML porque mi idea era ir cambiando la figura y modificando los puntos según necesite

```
<Polyline Points=" 10,488.2 286,1 562.17,488.2 10,488.2" StrokeThickness="1" Margin="116,110,181,43" Name="polylineObj" MouseEnter="polylineObj_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="polylineObj_MouseLeave" />
```

Pero resulta que cuando hago la asignación...

```
polylineObj = dibujoOriginal;
```

...la figura en pantalla no se me actualiza. 
Estuve debugueando y para mi sorpresa el polyline si cambia los puntos al hacer la asignación, pero esto no se demuestra en pantalla.

Me gustaría saber cual es mi error y que estoy omitiendo. Muchas gracias

Comment: Si haces cambios en el código y no se reflejan la mayoría de las veces es que necesitas implementar INotifyPropertyChanged, lo hiciste?

Comment: No, como debo hacer eso? y en que parte del código?

Comment: Lo coloqué como respuesta, tal vez eso te ayude, un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si haces modificaciones en el code-behind (código en el archivo .cs) y no se reflejan, sobretodo si estás usando Binding DEBES implementar la interface INotifyPropertyChanged, esto se hace así:

Primero:
En el archivo .cs de tu ventana, por ejemplo MiVentana.xaml.cs debes agregar lo siguiente:

```
public partial class MiVentana: Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

}
```

Entonces las variables de clase que usas para modificar las polylines las declaras así:

```
private Polyline _dibujoOriginal = new Polyline();
public Polyline DibujoOriginal
{
    get { return _dibujoOriginal; }
    set 
    {
        _dibujoOriginal = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("DibujoOriginal");
    }
}
```

De este modo cuando modifiques la variable DibujoOriginal esos cambios se comunicarán a la ventana que depende de este código..

Ojo! Para que esto funcione generalmente se usa Binding, así que en el constructor de la ventana (en el archivo .cs) agrega:

```
DataContext = this;
```

Y con eso está, la ventana sabrá que debe usar las variables propias.
Ojalá te ayude.

Comment: Me da error en "var handler = PropertyChanged;" Al parecer en PropertyChanged, es como si no existiera esa opción. (The name 'PropertyChanged' does not exist in the current context)

Comment: Que extraño, porque PropertyChanged está declarado en el ejemplo. Recuerda hacer el import para using System.ComponentModel.

Comment: Si si lo estoy usando esa librería. Lo extraño es que lo demás si me lo reconoce, lo unico que no me reconoce es el "PropertyChanged", ¿Estas seguro de que es así? Me aparecen otras opciones similares pero no esa.

Answer (score 1):

Muy buenas Gustavo,
¿Has probado a realizar un `Binding` en los puntos de la `PolyLine`?

Te dejo un ejemplo de como podrías realizarlo:

```
<Polyline StrokeThickness="1" 
          Margin="116,110,181,43" 
          Name="polylineObj" 
          MouseEnter="polylineObj_MouseEnter" 
          MouseLeave="polylineObj_MouseLeave"
          Points="{Binding Points}">
/Polyline>
```

Posteriormente en tu `codebehind` o en tu `viewModel`  tendrias algo como esto:

```
private PointCollection _points = new PointCollection();
public PointCollection Points
{
    get { return _points; }
    set { _points = value; }
}
```

En dicho `PointCollection` es donde podrías cambiar el valor de forma dinámica.
Te dejo un enlace con la información sobre el [PointCollection](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.pointcollection?view=netframework-4.7.2). Como puedes ver existe un metodo `Add` que te permite añadir nuevos puntos.

Un saludo

Comment: Disculpa, donde encuentro el codebehind?

Comment: Cuando hablo de CodeBehind me refiero al código que se incluye en el fichero .cs asociado a tu fichero xaml. En tu caso seria en el fichero  `MainWindows.xaml.cs`

Comment: Genial, me esta faltando la parte de asignar los puntos y pasarlos a la colleccion "Points", no se como hacer eso, disculpa, soy un poco novato en esto

Comment: Imagino que no te deja añadirle nada ya que solo se ha declarado para lectura la propiedad `Points` faltaria añadirle el `set`. Lo añado en el ejemplo.

Comment: Discúlpame pero la verdad estoy muy limitado en conocimientos supongamos que tengo una colección de puntos llamada trianguloUno. Como relaciono este objeto con lo que tu me estas proponiendo? Disculpa mi ignorancia, obviamente me faltan conceptos